# Data on Directed Technical Change

Tags: data-request, directed-technical-change, human-capital

I'm interested in technologies that are directed towards improving productivity of workers with high human capital.

What kind of data could one use to look at directed technical change, as in Howard-Howitt-Aghion, or Acemoglu (2002)?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to analyse the direction of technical change? Econometric analysis?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the literature has so far used three kinds of empirical analysis of the directed technical change.

1. **Illustration** based on the relationship between the relative supply of skills and the college premium as in [Acemoglu (2002)](https://economics.mit.edu/files/4126).
2. **Quantitative Analysis** to shed light on the theory as in [Acemoglu, Gancia, and Zilibotti (2015)](https://economics.mit.edu/files/11350). They match key moments and simulate their model.
3. **Estimate elasticities of substitution between more and less educated workers**. [Behar (2009)](https://www.economics.ox.ac.uk/materials/working_papers/paper467.pdf) use four types of data to estimate those elasticities, namely (i) cross sections, (ii) a long range panel of 40 observations,(iii) time series for Brazil and (iv) an annual panel for Latin America.